# flat validation loss (underfitting or goodfitting)

Tags: loss

if we have a loss like this plot, is it kind of underfitting or goodfitting?
[image]

Error results:
[image]

Training Process:
[image]

Comment: The loss of the first training batch probably is an outlier that does not let you see the details of the curves past it. I suggest that you remove it and check how it looks.

Comment: Your y axis scale is incorrect because what you want to measure are values very close to 0. You should plot log(loss) instead of loss. The same is true for validation. Log makes it way more readable for values close to 0.